# Postgis query to update linestring

Tags: postgis

while executing this query i am getting error

```
UPDATE treedetailsentered
 set geom_line=st_geomfromtext('LineString(('||longitude||' '||latitude||','||lon2||' '||lat2||'))', 4326);
```

error

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "LineString((7" <-- parse error at position 13 within geometry
********** Error **********
```

this is how i created column in table for the linestring

```
ALTER TABLE public.treedetailsentered
  ADD COLUMN geom_line geometry(LineString, 4326)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the exact problem is without knowing what type `longitude`, `latitude` have, but my guess is that you're not forming a proper string.

My advice is to debug this by first creating a proper text via a query that's simpler:

```
select 'LineString(('||longitude||' '||latitude||','||lon2||' '||lat2||'))'
```

Depending on what types you have, you might have to do some conversions, like this:

```
select 'LineString(('||longitude::text||' '||latitude::text||','||lon2::text||' '||lat2::text||'))'
```

If you already have texts, make sure that the numbers are properly formatted. Floats are expected to have a dot decimal separator for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have added an extra bracket i removed that it worked for me.

UPDATE treedetailsentered set geom_line=ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(' || longitude || ' '||latitude||','||lon2||' '||lat2||')', 4326);